# How to play a sound from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I am able to show a message box in BroadcastReceiver. How do I play a sound instead?

Comment: please add more description and if possible code also.

Answer (score -1):

Please review this code, I think help full for you...

> intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class); dd
>   calendar.a(Calendar.SECOND, 3); AlarmManager alarmManager =
>   (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
>   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
>   sender); // } });

after this the broadcast receiver it it shows an msg instead of playing a sound for the alarm

Comment: I have a class Alarm which looks like:

Comment: intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        
             
             dd calendar.a(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
                 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
                
//              
            }
            
        });   after this the broadcast receiver it it shows an msg instead of playing a sound for the alarm

Comment: So my question is how to play a sound instead of msgbox in BroadCast Receriver class

Comment: In the class Receiver which extends BroadCastReceiver i have just an Toast which shows a msg but what i want is to play a sound instead fo msg box

Comment: means your application is based on alarm,

Comment: yeahs it is based on alarm, it is comming the alarm but only Toast, instead of toast i wanna play a sound, is that possible?

Comment: Yes possible, the check your device setting the the alarm setting can be work properly and test as demo from device site after that doing another changes in your application....

Comment: I am saying for your device setting, please check your device setting and test alarm manually in the device after that test application alarm feature....

Comment: I think u are not understanding me, why should I check my alarm settings on my device since I am not having any code except Toast on my BroadCastReceiver class. lol im asking you for code how to play sound instead of a toast, did u get???

Comment: okey, then I will send you some link and there some code for alarm play, you will replace it in your code at toast place.